# What do the values in font preferences mean in org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs?

Tags: eclipse

I need to change Eclipse font settings from an external tool and I am trying to figure out what the different values in the preference file mean.

In `...\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs` 
I have these values:

```
org.eclipse.jface.textfont=1|Courier New|9.75|0|WINDOWS|1|-13|0|0|0|400|0|0|0|-18|3|2|1|49|Courier New;
```

I can figure out what some of them mean by changing font settings in the Preferences but what about the rest of them?

This is what I have found so far:

```
1|Courier New|9.75|0    |WINDOWS|1|-13|0|0|0|400 |0     |0        |0        |-18   |3|2|1|49|Courier New;
?|font       |size|style|?      |?|?  |?|?|?|bold|italic|underline|strikeout|script|?|?|?|? |font       ;
```